# Scanf countdown

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, scanf

I am making a scanf countdown via objective-C, so the program will count down from what ever number you input. However, there's an annoying semantic error in the code saying:Data argument not used by format string. Also the program doesn't countdown, it just displays the output as zero once I input a number.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        int x,number;

        NSLog(@"please enter a number:");
        scanf("i", &number);
        for (x = number;  x>=0; x--)
            NSLog(@"%i",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `%i`, not `i` in the format string of `scanf`.

When you pass `i`, the format string has zero format specifiers, leading to the semantic analyzer to produce a warning. That's also the reason why nothing gets entered into your `number` variable, so the countdown does not happen either.

Comment: Thanks, I'm relieved that it was just a simple typo in the syntax

Comment: @user1706978 You are welcome! If you tried the solution and it works for you, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark outline. This would indicate to others that yo are no longer looking for an improved solution, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.